# SMTP error in thunderbird to particalar email

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird

I am sending a mail through thunderbird and it shows a problem but all other mails on other id are delivering.

[image]

If i send this same mail from gmail.com from browser it delivers. What is and where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the email adres

Comment: Ok its kind of funny i am removing quotes but automatically it comes again and the error message appears again.